# Ion Wind Thruster? What is the theory behind it?

Tags: electromagnetism, aircraft

I am 18 and I am a university student studying aerospace engineering. While I am looking up Elon Musk's Electric jet plane I found this http://inhabitat.com/mit-developing-ionic-wind-thrusters-as-efficient-alternative-to-jet-engines/
There are a few points I don't quite understand:

1. They mentioned: "Ionic thrusters depend on the wind produced between two electrodes, and the larger the space between the electrodes, the stronger the thrust." what would that configuration look like? And with that much space, how could they ionize all of the intaked air?
2. This http://www.electric-vehiclenews.com/2009/07/will-plasma-jet-engines-ever-replace.html website talkes about "The combination of arc and high pressure/small nozzle creates a supersonic (9,000 mph) superheated (25,000 F) plasma stream that in a plasma cutter application vaporises steel and in a jet motor could replace the fuel combustion process. " How could ionizing something could add so much speed to the air. Also, would ionizing air coming out of a small nozzle and ionizing air in the compression stage of a jet engine share the same method?

Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: The website I found is talking about airplane engines though.

Comment: The technology for spacecraft is mature, and it's essentially the same principle. There are problems transfering it to aircraft thrust applications - mainly increasing the low thrust levels and runing it in an atmosphere not a vacuum. Be clear their plasma jet engine sounds like an entirely different animal from the ionic thruster.

Comment: Could you tell me anywhere I can find more information about this technology? And what do you mean by "different animal"?

Comment: I mean it seems to use a conventional fuel with the ion discharged used to ignite it. Here's a nasa link https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html

Comment: But the website I found says it is made by MIT and are for airplanes and they use no fuels though

Comment: @JMLCarter No, ionic wind thrusters and ion thrusters are not the devices.

Comment: This question has been modified/improved beyond the scope of my earlier cooment

Answer (score 1):

Your two questions concern entirely different devices/approaches to electric propulsion. Also, ion thrusters as used on satellites have little to do with those two approaches.

With regard to question 1:

You seem to have in mind the conventional setup in a ducted jet engine. This is not the case. The setup you need to have in mind is an ionocraft https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionocraft
Those devices work by charging two electrodes of different geometry to a very high-voltage (hundreds of kV). One of the electrode, usually the positive one, is designed with a very small radius of curvature forming sharp edges while the other electrode has a large radius of curvature (smooth and rounded). The electric field around the sharp electrode is designed to be high enough to ionize the surrounding air, forming a cloud of ionized air of the same charge as the electrode surrounding it. This ionized cloud is repelled by the sharp electrode and attracted to the smooth second electrode, where it is neutralized upon contact. The asymmetry in the geometry of the electrodes is to favor this effect happening in one direction and not the other to create a net ionic wind between the electrodes. If that was the end of the story there wouldn't be any (or negligible) net thrust generated to the setup.

The thrust comes from the transfer of momentum from the accelerated ionized particles between electrodes and the air by collisions. This momentum transfer creates a net neutral wind that creates the thrust. As such, the thrust generation is a volume effect happening between the two electrodes. The ionized particles are continuously accelerated in the gap while they collide with the air and a larger gap enables a higher momentum transfer to the surrounding air. Of course, a larger gap also means a higher potential difference between the electrodes is required to maintain the same acceleration of ions in the gap and one could ask what is gained with larger gaps. However, a non-negligible part of the input energy is used up upon first ionizing the air. Thus a longer gap yields more momentum transfer for the same ionization losses.

Now for question 2:

Be aware that the article mentions two different propulsion devices. At the beginning the discuss an magnetohydrodynamic (MHD) thuster which requires a conductive gluid medium too operate. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_drive) This medium can be water, molten salt, mercury, etc. Air cannot be used directly as it is not conductive. Thus, the thruster they discuss first ionizes the air to slightly conductive state so that an MHD thruster can then be used. This is where ionization plays a role in the second article you linked.

Now, the quote you gave concerns yet another entirely different scheme that the author speculate about. The idea is to use a conventional jet-engine, where instead of producing heat using combustion, you produce it by an arc discharge much the same as the discharges used in arc welding. Ionization has nothing to do with the principle behind the idea. Yes, superheated plasma will have different hydrodynamical properties than regular air which would presumably need to be taken into account when engineering such a device, but this has nothing to do with the core idea. Hence, your question about ionization is unrelated. Ionization does not accelerate air by itself. The extreme heating produced by an arc followed by a nozzle is what is doing the acceleration.

Last but not least, the creation and acceleration of jet for aerospace propulsion using electrically powered means is not at all the limiting technology that prevents the massive deployment of electrical crafts. This limitation is rather in the power source. Look at the specific energy column on the following page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density Do you notice how jet fuel has a specific energy ~40 times that of modern Li-po batteries? Now one could try to design an electric power source using jet fuel or diesel, but if one includes the weight of this generator in the specific energy calculation, then one gets abysmal specific energy. This is in part because most generators relies on a thermodynamical cycle with limited theoretical efficiency. One could also suggest using fuel-cells, but we haven't been able to even approach the specific power of modern jet-engine. So short of having a nuclear reactor on-board, electrical planes make little sense we figure out means of increasing the power/energy density of power supplies.

As a side comment, if one was to use a nuclear reactor, then generating electricity first makes no-sense as one could directly use the heat such as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_thermal_rocket Yes those thing could be made to fly ''forever'' using existing technology, but they pose a radiation hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't entirely agree with the talk above. I am a senior engineer with 19 years of experience working with ion propulsion. However, if you would like to see 9 prototype ion propelled aircrafts with onboard power, please check out my YouTube channel below:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_trtRcbCLO9Q2CzbKAya3w

Comment: Without giving any more details, you are not enhancing the discussion. On what, exactly, do you disagree? In view of your link, I suppose it relates to the ionocrafts? What I said concerning the ionocraft comes from the few studies published, in particular, the US military study on the efficiency of ionocrafts. As an aside: Integrating an HV inverter and Li-Po pack on a large ionocraft is nice, but be wary of the ground effect when claiming self-contained aircrafts. It does not seem ruled out from what I saw in the videos...

Comment: Hi G. Bergeron,  There are about 27 flight videos of the patented Self Contained Ion Powered (propelled) Aircraft on the Ethan Krauss YouTube channel.  The crafts generally all take off on about 40 to 60% throttle.  Earlier models of the craft lifted their power supplies momentarily under a postal scale in since 2006.  Most of the flights were out of ground effect. There is a video of it shown that flies vertically over 7 feet high. The studies you refer to are correct for older versions of the technology.  There is a 40 minute long detailed explanation of how the craft works on the channel.